# waiting for a return message with time out

Tags: c#, client-server, wait

I want to make connection conformation

what I have now is

```
internal bool connect(remoteIP)
{
 if ( network.startping(RemoteIP))
 {
  peer1.write("Hello!") ---> waits for "connected" until time out 
  if (Isconnected) return true
 }
 else 
  {
   try again after few sec with finite number of repeats
  }
 return false
}
```

1) what can I do to wait 
I saw a way with `Task wait = new task.factory(()=> doDwaiting())` 
with I think can work , but I I'm missing some logic here 
2) how can I make the return 
i think I can Do it with  `int Counter` and `goto` but it deosnt look like the "good" way to go

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the BeginConnect from the TcpClient class to verify the connection is valid.  A System.Timer object would be used to reconnect if the connection failed.  An example of a connection method would be as follows:

```
    public void Connect(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, double reconnectInterval)
    {
        _reconnectTimer = new Timer { Interval = _reconnectInterval, Enabled = false, AutoReset = false };
        _reconnectTimer.Elapsed += ReconnectTimer_Elapsed;

        _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            _tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipAddress, port, ConnectionRequestCallback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LostConnection(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

The LostConnection method is called when there is any type of connection failure.  The responsibility of the LostConenction method is to start the timer.

```
_reconnectTimer.Start();
```

Finally the timer's callback calls the same code shown above to attempt a new connection to the remote host.

```
Connect(_endPoint.Address, _endPoint.Port, _reconnectTimer.Interval);
    }
```

Comment: Hi 
_reconnectTimer is NOT configured right , I need to add timercallback.
what do think I need to add here ?